Why Allah created people knowing that some of them will end up in hell
What does it tell for the personality of Allah the fact that Allah created a human being knowing that the latter will end up in hell. Allah knew this fact, even before that human was brought to life.
Therefore, my main question is this: Does this fact conflict with the fact that Allah's personality is described as merciful?
Does it make sense in this case to discuss even for justice? Let me elaborate more on my question. If it is known before its birth that a person will not stay in paradise, simply means that that person will not have the capacity to understand God's Existence. It means that the person is not equipped with this capacity by the creator. Following the same logic flow, is it the person's fault that he is not provided with the faculty to understand? Apparently, the logical answer is no. Then, why does the person have to go to hell for smth that is beyond its control?
Does even make sense to state that the person has free will?

This is the issue of Compatibilism. Compatibilism = 1) Acknowledging divine decree 2) Acknowledging Human free will. This has been a topic debated even pre-Islam and you can find it in books of Greek Philosophers too like Stoicism.
The stoics used to argue that even if there is pre-destination,the human is ultimately responsible for his actions and not blame it on Pre-destination which would lead to collapse of social order and society.

Allah created some people for hell and some people for paradise.

The above hadith acknowledges Gods decree ( Predestination ).
And say, 'The truth is from your Lord, so whoever wills—let him believe; and whoever wills—let him disbelieve" - Al Kahf 29

Similarly the above aayah can be used for free-will claim.
But this creates a paradox. If anything impacts free-will of a human then it doesn't remain a free-will. So does Gods predestination impact the free-will? if yes, then its not really a free-will. If no, then whats the point of predestination?
You're not the first one to be confused regarding Free-will and Qadr. This topic of compatibilism remains as one of the most debated historically.
Some argue that the limitations of Human mind cannot really understand such grandiose of a concept.
Some resources for you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yvbnaT5DQ9w&t=678s
